# How to display data from two tables using EntityDataSources?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm in the process of creating a shopping cart for a company that sells phone numbers. To buy a phone number the "Customer" needs go through various steps to configure their phone number as they go along.

- Step One: Pick a phone number
- Step Two: Add a call package to this number
- Step Three: Add additional features i.e. Voicemail etc...
- Step Four: Review Order & Checkout

So far my approach has been a wizard style process where I store the Customers selections in a table within a database called NumberCart. This stores all the information for steps one and two.

Step Three is a little trickier because the Customer can have a number of options associated with their chosen number. To try and tackle this I decided to store their feature choices in a seperate table called FeatureCart.

I have been utilising the Entity Framework to retrieve and insert data. The Data Model can be viwed by cutting and pasting this link (Because I'm a newbie, Stackoverflow will only allow me to post two links).

[ armourcreative.co.uk/EntityDesignerDiagram.bmp ]

My Question is, is there a way to retrieve both tables and render the results in a webpage so that it displays like the image on the link below?

[Example Cart Render of exactly what I want to achieve](http://www.armourcreative.co.uk/cart.jpg)

All I can seem to get is two EntityDataSources connected to NumberFeatureView and NumberPackageView on the same page which renders like the image in the link below:

[Example Cart Render of not what I'm looking for](http://www.armourcreative.co.uk/cart2.jpg)

As you can see not a very clear way to display the users choices because it doesn't associate the feature with phone number it belongs to.

My thought is to somehow display the NumberFeatureView based on CartID and NumberID matching that of the NumberPackageView.

If anyone can tell me how to accomplish the above, I'd be very grateful. I might be way off the mark which is why I'm desperate for help and guidance.

#### REVISION

Okay, I have managed to get he cart to render correctly using the below code:

```
    <h3>Please review your order!</h3>
<asp:ListView ID="NumberPackageView_LV" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="NumberPackageView_EDM">

    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        No data was returned.
    </EmptyDataTemplate>


    <ItemTemplate>
        <li style="">
            <asp:HiddenField ID="ID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("NumberID") %>' />
            <strong><asp:Label ID="NumberLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Number") %>' /></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&rarr;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="DestinationLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Destination") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="PkgNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PkgName") %>' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="PkgMonthlyLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:c}",(Eval("PkgMonthly"))) %>' />


            <!-- ENTITY DATA SOURCE FOR FEATURES -->

<asp:ListView ID="NumberFeatureView_LV" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="NumberFeatureView_EDM">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        No data was returned.
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li style="">
            <asp:Label ID="FeatureNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FeatureName") %>' />
            <asp:Label ID="FeatureSetUpLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:c}", (Eval("FeatureSetUp"))) %>' />
            <asp:Label ID="FeatureMonthlyLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:c}", (Eval("FeatureMonthly"))) %>' />
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="">
            <li runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>



<asp:EntityDataSource ID="NumberFeatureView_EDM" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateWhereClause="True" ConnectionString="name=ShoppingCartv2Entities" 
    DefaultContainerName="ShoppingCartv2Entities" EnableFlattening="False" 
    EntitySetName="NumberFeatureViews" 
    Select="it.[FeatureName], it.[FeatureSetUp], it.[FeatureMonthly]" Where="">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="CartID" SessionField="ShoppingCartv2_CartId" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>

<!-- ENTITY DATA SOURCE FOR FEATURES [END] -->

 </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="">
            <li runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

<asp:EntityDataSource ID="NumberPackageView_EDM" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateWhereClause="True" ConnectionString="name=ShoppingCartv2Entities" 
    DefaultContainerName="ShoppingCartv2Entities" EnableFlattening="False" 
    EntitySetName="NumberPackageViews" 
    Select="it.[NumberID], it.[Number], it.[Destination], it.[PkgName], it.[PkgMonthly]" Where="">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="CartID" SessionField="ShoppingCartv2_CartId" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

My only problem now is that because the results are being filtered on the Session Cart, it's repeating all the features stored in FeatureCart under each number rather than displaying the feature that was selected against that specific number. (This only happens if the Customer adds more than one phone number to their shopping cart)

Example:

0800 123 0001

- Feature Voicemail
- Feature Call Recording
- Feature Ring Group

0800 123 0002

- Feature Voicemail
- Feature Call Recording
- Feature Ring Group

#### INSTEAD OF

0800 123 0001

- Feature Ring Group

0800 123 0002

- Feature Voicemail
- Feature Call Recording

Can anyone tell me how I go about only showing the features selected against the relevant number rather than the same selection for each number (if that makes sense?)

Answer (score 0):

An option you may want to try is to create a List and store the rows from both tables in that list, then bind the list to the grid. For example:

```
public class Main
{

    public void BindData()
    {
        List<MyList> myResults = new List<MyList>();

        //Add rows from numbercart to list object
        foreach (var item in NumberCart)
        {
            myResults.Add(new MyList { Item = item.item, Price = item.price });
        }

        //Add rows from feature cart to list object
        foreach (var item in FeatureCart)
        {
            myResults.Add(new MyList { Item = item.item, Price = item.price });
        }

        //Bind to datagrid
        myDataGrid.DataSource = myResults;

    }
}



public class MyList
{
    public string Item {get; set;}
    public float Price {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Hi Jerry, Thanks for taking the time to help me with my question. I like your suggestion but I'm new to all this and have never used lists before (I'm on a steep learning curve!). I have implemented the above code into my project but wondered if you could shed some light on how I'd display the data by binding myResults with myDataGrid? Is it literally a case of giving the GridView an ID of myDataGrid? Also I get the follwing error on these two lines: (var item in NumberCart) and (var item in FeatureCart). Both say (is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'), Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, I would create a datagrid named myDataGrid and set it's DataSource = myResults. Also, I should have put "foreach (var item in NumberPackageView_EDM)" and "foreach (var item in NumberFeatureView_EDM)". Give that a try.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, Jerry but now I've implemented the changes I get an error saying "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSource' because 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSource' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'" - Any ideas on this? Your time and effort is greatly aprreciated!